# VBA ADO: Could Not Use <Filename>; file already in use

Tags: vba, ms-access, adodb

It's been a long time since I've had to do any development in Access, so hoping I can get some help. I have a split Front End/Back End solution that I've built. The Back End resides on a server, the front end gets copied down to user's desktops (and they use runtime Access 2013). I'm using Access with VBA and ADO connections/recordsets in order to do all record actions (Select, inserts, updates mostly).

Two intermittent issues have cropped up and I'm at a loss - this is one of them. From time to time, some users will get the error "Could not use "(back end Filename)"; file already in use." (where (back end filename) is my back end db name & location". When users get this message, they close out, re-open and try the same data entry and it works without a hitch. Here's the code:

```
Private Sub SetProblemCode()
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

strSQL = "SELECT Problem_Code_ID, Problem_Code, Problem_Description FROM Problem_Code ORDER BY Problem_Description"

con.Open strConString
rstProblemCode.CursorLocation = adUseClient
rstProblemCode.Open strSQL, con, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly

cboProblemCode.RowSourceType = "Table/Query"

Set cboProblemCode.Recordset = rstProblemCode

rstProblemCode.Close
con.Close

Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    CriticalError Err.Description, Err.Number, Me.Name, "SetProblemCode"

End Sub
```

The rst and con objects are defined at the global level, a practice I've used in other solutions before but I'm questioning if that's some of the problem. I'm also questioning the cursor location, type and lock type I'm using, although it seems correct - I'm not altering data, just copying a recordset to the Access combo box.

I'm hesitant to make sweeping changes when it seems like the user closes out and tries again and it works just fine. Any thoughts?

Comment: You can add `;Mode=Read` to the connection string or don't use the globals

Comment: Ok, giving both of those suggestions a try tonight.

Comment: I moved all my connections and recordsets to be defined in the subs. We went from having several of these messages a day to just occasional ones, so I'm inclined to say it helped, but didn't fix it.

Comment: How can I implement the ;Mode=Read into the connection string?

Comment: I think it is related to the connection not being disposed of properly, which is usually more likely to happen with global variables. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5942936/readonly-connection-string-to-an-access-database

Comment: I stumbled upon that article a bit ago. They aren't globals anymore, and that has helped. I'm going to try the ;Mode=Read pretty soon and see if that helps.